# How can I measure the elapsed time when ecnrypting using Openssl in linux

Tags: encryption, openssl, measure

I don't know how could I measure the elapsed time in encryption using openssl.

I have downloaded openssl to my linux system with no problems and I can do encryption to different files but I don't know how to measure the time to see what encryption algorithm is more effecient.

Here is the command that I use to do the encryption:

```
 OpenSSL> enc -des-cbc -salt -a -in "/usr/local/openssl/file1.txt" -out "/usr/local/openssl/file1_des.enc" -k "123456"
```

This is the other algorithm:

```
 OpenSSL> enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -a -in "/usr/local/openssl/file2.txt" -out "/usr/local/openssl/file2_aes.enc" -k "123456"
```

Is there a way to measure the time of execution? I tried to open another terminal and execute the (time) but it didn't help. I also don't have that much of experice on using linux. However, I tried to do the same thing on Windows but still don't have a way to measure the time.

Hope you guys can help.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, I entered this at the shell prompt:

```
 time openssl enc -des-cbc -salt -a -in foo.txt -out foo_des.enc -k "123456"
```

and got the output:

```
real    0m0.214s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.016s
```

That said, you'd get a more meaningful result if you introduced some sort of looping construct.  At the very least, consider creating a text file with multiple `openssl` command lines:

opensslcmds.txt:

```
enc -des-cbc -salt -a -in foo.txt -out file1_des.enc -k 123456
enc -des-cbc -salt -a -in foo.txt -out file2_des.enc -k 123456
enc -des-cbc -salt -a -in foo.txt -out file3_des.enc -k 123456
(and so on)
```

and then run

```
time openssl < opensslcmds.txt
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much.. This was really helpful. I didn't know how to use the time with the openssl.. you're the man!

Answer (score 4):

Eh, you mean like `openssl speed`?

Comment: no the speed gives an overall benchmark, but I wanted something more specific depending on specific files to encrypt. I need to see the difference between different algorithms when they encrypt actual files. Thanx tho cuz QuantumMechanic answered the question.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you get a mix of IO performance with encryption performance. E.g. disk cache may play a very important role. In the end you may have varying figures depending on the load of the CPU and the disk & memory configuration. You may want to use both methods to calculate specific scenarios.